# Parse json array in jquery and Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following response returned in json, but I am unable to parse results into JQuery view. I have tried with `data.prodotto[0]` but does not work. I have also tried to use `data.prodotto` which returns "undefined"

[image]

My Ajax request is:

```
$.ajax({ 
url: 'carrello-ajax', 
type: "post", 
data: {
      'id_tariffa':id_tariffa, 
      'tipo_soglia':tipo_soglia, 
      'cod_carrello':cod_carrello, 
      'quantita':quantita, 
      '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
}, 
success: function(data){ 
if ( data.OK == 1 ) { 
var mod_carrello_original = $("#mod_carrello2").html(); $('#add_to_cart').hide('fast'); 
$('#mod_carrello').html('<h1 align="center" style="color:green; font-size: 21.5em;"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i></h1><br><br><h3 align="center">Servizio aggiunto correttamente al carrello</h3>');
```

I need to use field "quantità" in my .html jquery injection.

How can I achieve this result?

This work is built in Laravel 5.1

Comment: please try with `data.prodotti.item[0].quantita `

Comment: unfortunately not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to log data in success function and check what is there.
Like this

```
success: function(data){ 
console.log("data from server",data);
}
```

or add debug point in success function and check what is there in data object.
And if it prints in object format then it will work other it may be that data will contain only string or anything else.
So just check that fields are their before accessing them through data object.